# Can't get gaussian blur to match Sketch

Tags: ios, swift, blur, gaussianblur

I am trying to replicate a Gaussian blur in swift in my application, but the core image filter doesn't seem to act the same way as the Sketch Gaussian blur.  I need the blur to cover the UIImage as well as extend past the bound of the UIImage and blur the area around it.  When I try to use CIFilter, it either clips the blur to the edges of the image or insets the image and makes it appear much smaller than it is.  Is there a better way to make a Gaussian blur that will match the Sketch functionality?

Comment: Use a visual effect view, it will create a blur using the content around it's bounds too.

Comment: Using a visual effects view will make the edges of the blur visible, I need the edges to fade out softly without noticing the edges

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?